# Watchtower in Die2Nite, how exactly does it work?

Tags: die2nite

Using the watchtower the town can estimate the size of the coming zombie attack. The more citizens use the watchtower, the better the estimate becomes.

- Is the number of people needed reduced when people die? Or does it always take the same amount of people to get an estimate, regardless of the town population?
- How many people are needed for the initial estimate?
- Is the real zombie number always within the estimate? Or can the estimate be deceiving?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the number of people is around 10, although it can be reduced by building the scanner.  It is not reduced when people die, so if your town population has been drastically reduced, you can reach a point where you don't have enough people to estimate the next day's attack.  The real number is always within the estimate.

Answer (score 3):

The real zombie number is *always* within the estimates.

Answer (score 0):

Every vote added 11% last time i checked. With 6 survivors, we never got any estimates.